# Decorator, that changes type of value

Tags: python, python-decorators

I want to create decorators, which will change type of returning value:

```
class TypeDecorators:
    def to_int(self, f):
        def inner(*args):
            try:
                return int(f(*args))
            except:
                return None
        return inner
    
    def to_str(self, f):
        ...

    def to_bool(self, f):
        ...
    
    def to_float(self, f):
        ...
    
@TypeDecorators.to_str
def do_nothing(self, string: str):
    return string

@TypeDecorators.to_int
def do_something(self, string: str):
    return string

print(do_nothing('25'))
print(do_something('25'))
```

But its not working, anyone have any idea? Getting this error:

```
TypeError: to_str() missing 1 required positional argument: 'f'
```

Comment: Make each of your `def to_...` methods `@staticmethod`.

Comment: You can probably write a single decorator generator that takes the desired type as its argument: `@change_type_to(int) def do_something(...): ...`

Comment: Why are you using a class here? For your decorators to work as written, you'd need to use `@TypeDecorators().to_int`

Comment: I use a class because I have to, it is task

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a bunch of nearly identical decorators. Just define one parameterized decorator that takes as its argument the desired return type.

```
def change_to(t: type):
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapper(x):
            # Do this first, so you don't catch any exception *it* might raise
            rv = f(x)
            try:
                return t(rv)
            except ValueError:
                return None
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@change_to(str):
def do_nothing(x: str):
    return x


@change_to_(int):
def do_something(x: str):
    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, so I've added extra information why *argumented decorator* shown above needs nested wrappers.

this is basic decorator:

```py
def deco(func):
    print(f"wrapping {func} at IMPORT TIME!")
    return func


@deco
def some_function():
    pass
```

even without calling `some_function` script prints out line:

```
wrapping <function some_function at 0x000001667FB0BCA0> at IMPORT TIME!
```

From this we learned `@deco` is actually just a syntax sugar of `some_function = deco(some_function)`.

Therefore decorators get only one argument, target function.

However, for *argumented* decorator you **calls** a decorator function unlike normal decorators:

```
def deco():
    print(f"inside deco!")  # called on import-time
    def inner_deco(func):
        print(f"inside inner_deco!")  # also called on import-time
        def wrapper(*args):
            print(f"inside wrapper!")  # will be called in run-time
            func(*args)
        return wrapper

    return inner_deco

@deco()
def some_function():
    pass
```

is essentially just a cool way of doing this:

```
inner_deco = deco()

def b():
   pass

b = inner_deco(b)
```

One good example of built-in simple decorator would be `@functools.singledispatch`, other one would be `@functools.wraps(original_func)`.

---

same solution I was writing:

```py
from functools import wraps


def typed_decorator(target_type):

    def decorator_inner(func):
        @wraps(func)  # this copy signature of given function to wrapper for easier debugging.
        def wrapper(*args):
            return target_type(func(*args))

        return wrapper

    return decorator_inner


@typed_decorator(int)
def do_something(val):
    return val


@typed_decorator(bool)
def do_other(val):
    return val


print(type(do_something("20")))
print(type(do_other("30")))
```

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'bool'>
```